# Spark structured streaming - join static dataset with streaming dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using `Spark structured streaming` to process records read from `Kafka`. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

(a) Each record is a `Tuple2` of type `(Timestamp, DeviceId)`.

(b) I've created a static `Dataset[DeviceId]` which contains the set of all valid device IDs (of type `DeviceId`) that are expected to be seen in the `Kafka` stream.

(c) I need to write a `Spark structured streaming` query that

```
 (i) Groups records by their timestamp into 5-minute windows
 (ii) For each window, get the list of valid device IDs that were **not** seen in that window
```

For example, let's say the list of all valid device IDs is `[A,B,C,D,E]` and the kafka records in a certain 5-minute window contain the device IDs `[A,B,E]`. Then, for that window, the list of unseen device IDs I'm looking for is `[C,D]`.

**Question**

1. How can this query be written in Spark structured streaming? I tried using the `except()` and `join()` methods that `Dataset` exposes. However, they both threw a runtime exception complaining that neither of those operations is supported on a `streaming Dataset`.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```scala
val validDeviceIds: Dataset[(DeviceId, Long)] = spark.createDataset[DeviceId](listOfAllDeviceIds.map(id => (id, 0L))) 

case class KafkaRecord(timestamp: TimestampType, deviceId: DeviceId)

// kafkaRecs is the data stream from Kafka - type is Dataset[KafkaRecord]
val deviceIdsSeen = kafkaRecs
     .withWatermark("timestamp", "5 minutes")
     .groupBy(window($"timestamp", "5 minutes", "5 minutes"), $"deviceId")
     .count()
     .map(row => (row.getLong(0), 1L))
     .as[(Long, Long)]

val unseenIds = deviceIdsSeen.join(validDeviceIds, Seq("_1"), "right_outer")
     .filter(row => row.isNullAt(1))
     .map(row => row.getLong(0))
```

The last statement throws the following exception:

```scala
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Right outer join with a streaming DataFrame/Dataset on the left is not supported;;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How large is the static dataset?

Comment: Probably a few tens of thousands of device IDs (eg: 10K - 50K)

Comment: use leftAnti or rightAnti joins in spark

Answer (score 6):

The situation with `join operations` in spark structured streaming looks as follows: streaming `DataFrames` **can be joined** with `static DataFrames` so in further create new `streaming DataFrames`. But `outer joins` between a `streaming` and a `static Datasets` are **conditionally** supported, while `right/left joins` with a `streaming Dataset` **are not supported** in general by structured streaming. As result, you faced with [AnalysisException](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala#L350-L353), which was thrown while you tried to make join static dataset with streaming dataset. As proof of my words, you can look at source code of spark, on this [line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c5f9b89dda40ffaa4622a7ba2b3d0605dbe815c0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala#L243) exception is throwing which denotes that operation which you tried out is not supported.

I tried to make join operation on `stream of DataFrames` with a static `DataFrames`.

```
val streamingDf = sparkSession
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "structured_topic")
    .load()

val lines = spark.readStream
      .format("socket")
      .option("host", "localhost")
      .option("port", 9999)
      .load()

val staticDf = Seq((1507831462 , 100)).toDF("Timestamp", "DeviceId")

//Inner Join
streamingDf.join(staticDf, "Timestamp")
line.join(staticDf, "Timestamp")

//Left Join
streamingDf.join(staticDf, "Timestamp", "left_join")
line.join(staticDf, "Timestamp", "left_join")
```

As you see, in addition to consuming data from `Kafka` I read data from the socket launched via `nc` (netcat), it significantly simplifies life while you make testing of stream app.
This approach works fine for me both with `Kafka` and `socket` as the source of data.

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I don't think that solves my use case. I need to find the device IDs that are present in the static dataset and absent in the streaming one. If I do a left join with the streaming dataset on the left, I wouldn't get that, right? Apart from joins, is there any other way of implementing this logic in spark structured streaming? Thanks again.

Comment: According to Spark specification - you can make left outer join with `structured streaming` and `static dataframe` but not with `dataset`, try to convert `dataframe` to `dataset` and moke join operation - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#join-operations

Answer (score 2):

Outer joins with streaming Dataset on opposite side [are just not supported](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations):

> - Outer joins between a streaming and a static Datasets are conditionally supported.
>
>   - Full outer join with a streaming Dataset is not supported
>   - Left outer join with a streaming Dataset on the right is not supported
>   - Right outer join with a streaming Dataset on the left is not supported

If other `Dataset` is small, you can use `Map` or similar structure, `broadcast`, and reference it inside `UserDefinedFunction`.

```
val map: Broadcast[Map[T, U]] = ???
val lookup = udf((x: T) => map.value.get(x))

df.withColumn("foo", lookup($"_1"))
```