# Using ksqldb to join data from multiple types of source connectors

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, etl, ksqldb

We are evaluating ksqldb as a ETL tool for our organization. Our entire app is hosted on Microsoft Azure and mostly PaaS offerings are preferable in our organization. However 1 use case is that we have multiple microservices with their own databases and we want to join the tables in the databases together to produce some data in a denormalized format for some other tasks. An example would be `Users` table containing user data whereas `Orders` table contains all the orders. `Users` maybe in SQL format in MySQL whereas `Orders` maybe in NoSQL format in MongoDB. Now we need to generate some report on by joining `Orders` and `Users` tables together based on `user_id`. This can be done in ksqldb by using some joins on streams/tables and adding source connectors to each of the databases. Then we can write a sink connector to a new MongoDB database that can have the joined `Users_Orders` info. So if new data is added and the connectors and joins are running our joined data in `Users_Orders` will also get updated.

With Azure Event Hub I read that using ksqldb in production will not be possible because of some [licensing issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview#kafka-streams). So my questions are:

Before going into some other products like Azure HDInsights or Confluent Cloud is there any way of running ksqldb to achieve the same solution (perhaps like managing your own Kafka cluster)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need ksql; you should be able to do something similar with SparkSQL, offered in Azure (Databricks) or Flink (HDInsights or AKS). You don't necessarily need Kafka / EventHub either since Spark/Flink can read, join, and write Mongo/JDBC data all on its own (with the appropriate plugins).

The main reason ksqlDB isn't a hosted service by Azure, is that it conflicts with Confluent Licensing, but that does not prevent you from running it yourself, as long as you also adhere to the licensing restrictions of not publicly offering the ksqlDB REST API as a publicly available / paid API. I've not personally tried, but ksqlDB should work against EventHubs on its own, I don't think you need to self manage Kafka as the documentation suggests.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to self-host KSQLDB and connect against Event Hub. Never tried this though.

Comment: @OneCricketeer can you post details? Overall, the suggested solution is not clear. As I understand Aritra wants to produce such an output in stream, whereas I can imaging using Databricks+connectors for batch approach. They don't even need Databricks & Spark for that, a simple Function would do, as such a simple join can be done programmatically. Databricks also can stream-process data, but for that they need to send data into supported streams like EventHubs. What exactly was you suggestion?

Comment: @greatvovan Details about what? Running ksql in Azure? Should be no different than anywhere else. Use a VM or a Container... Or why Azure cannot offer ksql as a service? I feel I already answered this, which is what the question was actually asking. Otherwise, yes, my suggestion was to not use ksql at all since there are other options, such as Spark which Azure does offer as a service, such as through Databricks, and that'll work with Mongo + JDBC, as the question asked. I only suggested that EventHubs/Kafka wouldn't be necessary, depending on the data needed to be processed

Comment: @OneCricketeer details about how exactly to use Spark for the purpose described by the poster. I know Spark can STREAM-process data from EventHubs, but you say it's not necessary, so I am wondering how exactly you suggest to stream and join data from MongoDB and MySQL as there seem to be missing pieces. Connectors may enable BATCH processing of such data in Spark, but in this case I don't understand why you would need Spark at all and it seems not what OP asked.

Comment: @greatvovan I said ksql is not necessary, and that Spark could be used in its place, within the context of Azure to do "something similar". I didn't state anything about streaming or CDC joined datasets. I said that Spark has connectors for both [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/) and [MySQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html). Stream/Batch wasn't the question, only usage of ksql for processing data. The question did not state that Kafka was actually used, which is a first requirement for ksql.

Comment: I saw 'joins on streams/tables' in the question, which made me think that real-time processing is required. Maybe I misinterpreted.

Comment: @greatvovan If a stream is materialized to a table in Spark, it can be joined https://stackoverflow.com/a/46716284/2308683